# MySQL deadlocking when deleting by certain columns

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a table with the following columns

```
document_uuid, driver_uuid, vehicle_uuid, etc
```

`document_uuid` is the primary key and is always unique.
`driver_uuid` is a required field and is not always unique.
`vehicle_uuid` is an optional field.

We're constantly deleting and adding rows to this table. The deletions are by driver_uuid or by document_uuid.

Today I added some code to occasionally delete by vehicle_uuid as well and that deployment started causing mysql to deadlock.

The deadlock exceptions do not show too much information:

```
'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction') [SQL: u'DELETE FROM documents_rich_context WHERE vehicle_uuid = %s']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a lack of an index on the vehicle_uuid field.

Without an index, the db engine has to grab a lot more rows to identify which rows to delete, causing a much higher chance of a deadlock.

Adding the index solved the issue.